# WFFM Timeout error on form report

Tags: wffm

On my site, some WFFM forms allow data to be downloaded in Excel format without any issues, whereas other forms seem to fail with a timeout error

> 500 - The request timed out.

In the Chrome network tab, the request seems to time out after 3.8 minutes (228 seconds), but on checking the web.config the timeout is set at 3600 seconds, so this should not be a timeout error.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000"
             executionTimeout="3600"
             enableKernelOutputCache="false"
             relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
             requestValidationMode="2.0"
             enableVersionHeader="false"/>
```

Is there some other setting specific to WFFM that I need to check?

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 and WFFM 8.2 rev 161129.

I have tried increasing the Sitecore settings, per the article suggested by Mark Cassidy, but this still does not work:

```
<setting name="DefaultSQLTimeout" value="00:10:00"/>
<setting name="DataProviderTimeout" value="00:10:00"/>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the case for WFFM, but maybe the general DataProviderTimeout?  https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/timeout-error-when-running-cleanupdatabases-job/

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy, I tried those suggestions, but no luck yet.