# WFFM how to manage large amounts of data

Tags: wffm

I have several WFFM forms in my solution. Some of them have a very large number of responses (30000+). When I attempt to download that form data, I get timeout errors and the whole CM server seems to grind to a halt producing repeated 500 timeout errors afterwards. Is there some way to download the data in chunks (by some filtering mechanism?) or is there some accepted approach for clearing out data after a certain age? This seems strange as I can write a query to bring back the equivalent data and that takes only a few seconds (albeit not nicely formatted with form fields as columns).

Answer (score 2):

Adding indexing onto the two WFFM database tables increases performance significantly, enough to eliminate the timeout issues. I used the following SQL script to add indexing to the `FieldData` and `FormData` tables and to rebuild the indexes.

```
--Create index on FieldData table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FormId] ON [dbo].[FieldData]
(
   [FormId] ASC
)WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Create index on FormData table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FormItemId] ON [dbo].[FormData]
(
    [FormItemId] ASC
)WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Rebuild indexes on FieldData table
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[FieldData]
REBUILD WITH (
    FILLFACTOR = 80,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);
GO

--Rebuild indexes on FormData table
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[FormData]
REBUILD WITH (
    FILLFACTOR = 80,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON);
GO
```

**Previous Comment**

After bringing a backup of our data and attaching it locally, I ran SQL Profiler while running the export. It seems that WFFM actually issues a separate SELECT statement for each form submission, which seems crazy to me. I guess this explains the slowness/timeouts when working with significant amounts of data. Not sure if there is a solution to this, beyond simply writing your own SQL query to extract the data.

Comment: There probably isn't. I think we've had this up before, somewhere.

Comment: Also: can we close this one? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/wffm-timeout-error-on-form-report

Comment: @MarkCassidy yes happy for you to close the other question - maybe you can mark it as a duplicate of this one? I was not able to vote close marking this as a duplicate.